# Can't call partials used in php using codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, partials

I'm a beginner and I made the _partials and I don't know where I did wrong.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/head.php") ?>
</head>
<body id="page-top">

<?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/navbar.php") ?>

<div id="wrapper">

  <?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/sidebar.php") ?>

  <div id="content-wrapper">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- 
        karena ini halaman overview (home), kita matikan partial breadcrumb.
        Jika anda ingin mengampilkan breadcrumb di halaman overview,
        silahkan hilangkan komentar (//) di tag PHP di bawah.
        -->
    <?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/breadcrumb.php") ?>

    <!-- Icon Cards-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-primary o-hidden h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-body-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-comments"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="mr-5">26 New Messages!</div>
        </div>
        <a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">
        <span class="float-left">View Details</span>
        <span class="float-right">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-warning o-hidden h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-body-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-list"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="mr-5">11 New Tasks!</div>
        </div>
        <a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">
        <span class="float-left">View Details</span>
        <span class="float-right">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-success o-hidden h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-body-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="mr-5">123 New Orders!</div>
        </div>
        <a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">
        <span class="float-left">View Details</span>
        <span class="float-right">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-danger o-hidden h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-body-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-life-ring"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="mr-5">13 New Tickets!</div>
        </div>
        <a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">
        <span class="float-left">View Details</span>
        <span class="float-right">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    <!-- Sticky Footer -->
    <?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/footer.php") ?>

  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->


<?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/scrolltop.php") ?>
<?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/modal.php") ?>
<?php $this->load->view("admin/_partials/js.php") ?>

</body>
</html>
```

If I just load it using my default controller, nothing is working. However if I load it by opening the directory (http://localhost/jtp2/index.php/admin), every javascript file receives an error from the console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

Any help is appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using only `$this->view($template, $data)`.

```
<?php $this->view("admin/_partials/navbar.php") ?>
```

Comment: So no load ? I'll try this

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the correct way to load view inside another view. What do  you mean by "nothing is working? Have you checked apache/nginx logs?

Comment: I tried but It doesn't fix my problem, no i haven't and how did i do that ? sorry im a beginner

Comment: Go to apache or nginx log directory and check latest logs.

Comment: i did but i don't think there's an error in the log, but if i follow your instruction, the error on the page console change to this ```GET http://localhost/jtp2/index.php/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: That .htaccess did you put in the same directory of index.php (project root folder)

Answer (score 0):

About the javascripts async calls reporting 404 it's probably because you are failing to hit the correct uri resource.

Check in the url you have `index.php/admin`. Probably your javascript ajax calls are looking for just `/admin/` or even `admin/`. So you must be aware of this uri path references on your calls.

I recommend you use some .htaccess mod rewrite type of solution to avoid having to specify your front controller `index.php` file in the url.

If you are under Apache usually the .htaccess mod rewrite looks as follows:

```
 RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Try to check the "Network" console and see what the urls you are trying to hit via ajax look like.

Comment: So i just put it on the root folder or in the admin folder ?

Comment: @MichaelRay you should put it in your root folder. At the same level ast `index.php` is.